# android how to know ringtone length

Tags: android

I'm working on a sample code same as http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media, I'm successfully playing the ringtone, but I want to know the length of the ringtone(in sec) or atleast a notification after end of the ringtone, so that i have to do some other task after playing the ringtone.

Thanks
nehatha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a MediaPlayer. You dont have to play it just .prepare() it. Then you can ask MediaPlayer about the duration.